# Android Intent Filters

Tags: android, android-intent, service, intentfilter, device-admin

I require my application to monitor the installed application on an android device and also get the details of the applications currently running on the foreground.
 The two possible solutions i can think of are:

1.Defining a  **sticky service** and checking continuously which application is being used would be one option but that would consume a lot of battery.

2.Another possible method i thought of could be implementing a **broadcast receiver**. We can set the intent-filter to actions like **SET_ALARM** and **RECEIVE** etc. Android has provided actions for every possible event like sending a message or receiving voice mail.

So my question is does any **action** exist for **launch of an application**?

If it did  I would just run an intent service from my broadcast receiver and that would do rest of the work without having to continuously poll if an application has been opened or not like I have mentioned in point 1.

Can anyone help or provide an alternative solution?

Comment: Hey r u answering something or questioning ? Didn't clear...

Comment: I have provided a solution I thought of.

Comment: Yes you can monitor the installed application like you can get the details of all installed apps...their ram usage,lnstalled date,last update date and you can also open that application from your app,you can also kill their background process and much more....But if you want to fire some alarm when one of installed application get open then in that case you can't do that....because other installed applications doesn't share their intent filters....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I guess there is no way to register a broadcast receiver to detect app launch. One of the way could be (similar to your suggestion):

```
// TO GET INSTALLED APPS
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> packageList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : packageList) {
    Log.d("ResolveInfo", "Package: " + resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
}

// TO GET INFO OF RUNNING PROCESSES
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : runningAppProcessInfos) {
    Log.d("runningAppProcessInfo", "Running process name: " + runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
}
```

And poll for status of apps you are interested in with [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I will start working on that line. !